# How to dump and recover sdcardfs

Tags: data-recovery, internal-sd

[Sdcardfs is a virtual file system](https://www.xda-developers.com/diving-into-sdcardfs-how-googles-fuse-replacement-will-reduce-io-overhead/) in Android or some Linux systems. It is implemented using FUSE.

It is called Android's 'adopted storage', is used in virtual sdcards, or protected partition areas. (For example: /storage/simulated/0)

If you try to dump an sdcard file system (ex: /sdcard) by dd command, It is not dumpable. (It does not have sectors or anything.

So, if I try to dump the parent file system (ex: 'FUSE like vFAT' on EXT4), it is not recoverable by all of commercial file recovery software. Because sdcardfs is a virtual file system using FUSE, it is not stored like a file or agglomerate something(s).

How can I dump and recover an sdcardfs file system?

Comment: FUSE is not a virtual filesystem. It's a framework that allows developers to write virtual filesystem drivers. On the other hand, `sdcardfs` is a virtual filesystem. The fact that it's implemented using FUSE is an implementation detail. What you're really asking is how to dump and restore an sdcardfs filesystem, right?

Comment: @Gilles yes. I asking about how to recover files in sdcardfs file system when having only dumped file system image(ex: mmcblk0, mmcblk0p12). the data on SdcardFS is not analysable by general FAT or EXT supported file recovery software.

Comment: And it is not mountable becuase it it not stored like a file or partition or agglomerate somethings, and SDcardFS do not supported read sector by sector, it can only read and write by file unit.

Comment: SdcardFS  is not a FUSE, it's an in-kernel solution.

Comment: `sdcardfs`, FUSE and Adoptable Storage are entirely different things. `sdcardfs` replaced Android's FUSE-based virtual filesystem. Both are used to emulate an actual underlying filesystem (`ext4` or `f2fs`) which is `/data/media` or (in case of Adoptable Storage) external SD card's 2nd partition. So if you want to do deleted file recovery, you need to do that on underlying actual filesystem. Just create a dump of block device. See [How to recover a deleted file from /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/218526).

Answer (score 1):

You can back up any filesystem by backing up individual files, e.g. in a tar archive. Assuming that you have a set of Linux command line utilities (e.g. a full BusyBox installation):

```
adb shell 'tar -cz /sdcard | uuencode sdcard.tar.gz' >sdcard.tar.gz.uu
uudecode sdcard.tar.gz.uu
```

The `uuencode`/`uudecode` step is necessary because adb corrupts binary files on output (it adds CR before every LF).

You can open the archive in any archive browser (except the one built into Windows, or at least older versions of Windows, because it only supports the zip format).

To restore:

```
adb shell 'cd /target/directory && tar -xz' <sdcard.tar.gz
```

I don't know if there's a lower-level tool to dump an sdcardfs filesystem. Since sdcardfs is a view of an underlying filesystem (i.e. a stackable filesystem), rather than a filesystem built on top of a storage device, there's nothing to dump. But the underlying filesystem *is* built on a storage device; if you dump that, you will get a full backup and you can access the sdcardfs part by using the sdcardfs driver on the backup and mounting it with the same parameters.

FUSE is pretty much irrelevant here. It's an implementation technique, not a description of the filesystem format.

Comment: I think OP is concerned about deleted data recovery, not backup/restore. **“the underlying filesystem is built on a storage device; if you dump that, you will get a full backup and you can access the sdcardfs part by using the sdcardfs driver on the backup and mounting it with the same parameters.”**. No. Dump of underlying filesystem is just `ext4` or `f2fs`, it doesn't have any ***sdcardfs part***.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Oh right, I hadn't caught on when I answered this, but indeed it seems that the question is about recovering a deleted file, and my answer doesn't help that. Regarding the part you quote — well, yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.