# How to recover a deleted file from /data partition on a rooted phone?

Tags: adb, root-access, data-recovery, ext4

I factory reset my rooted Android M phone but now I realize that there was a file in the ***/data*** directory which I need.

Is it possible to create an image (.img or something similar) of the /data partition so that I could run some recovery software for ext4 on that image? I have a little knowledge about ADB.

Comment: Duplicate: [Recover deleted content from userdata partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25948/218526)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First to clarify `root` and `data`:

- Root directory `/` of Android devices is a read-only pseudo (temporary) filesystem (`rootfs`) that lives in RAM and is vanished when device is powered off. When device is powered on, it's again extracted from `initramfs` that lives in `boot` partition along with kernel.

On newer devices with [system-as-root](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/system-as-root), `system` partition is mounted at root `/`.

- `/data` directory is a mountpoint, where largest partition, usually named `userdata` is mounted. This partition contains all user apps, their data (settings, databases, caches, temporary files etc.), system apps' data and all other configurations we make through `Settings`. `/data/media/0` is the directory that we see as `/sdcard` or `/storage/emulated/0` through [emulation](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526).

> ... there was a file in the /data directory which I need. Is it possible to create an image (.img or something similar) of the root directory ...

If a file is deleted from `/data`, you need to create a dump of `data` partition, not that of root directory.

You can do that in multiple ways described below. All require **root access**.

---

***But first of all, see [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214496/218526) to make sure your data is recoverable.***

In short, recovery is more or less possible only if <sup>([1](https://recoverhdd.com/blog/smartphones-and-data-recovery.html))</sup>:

- Your deleted data hasn't been `TRIM`med or `discard`ed.
- And you haven't done a factory reset on encrypted `/data` partition.

What you should do immediately:

- Switch off phone to make sure the deleted data isn't overwritten.
- Don't install data recovery apps on device, it can do more harm than good.
- Mount the filesystem (if required) in recovery mode (or on PC) only with `ro,nodiscard` options.

---

### FINDING BLOCK DEVICE:

In order to access the `userdata` partition, you need to find its block device. If you have root access, you can do so from mounted partitions:

```
~# mount | grep 'on /data'
/dev/block/mmcblk0p... on /data type f2fs (rw,nosuid,nodev,...)
```

On Qualcomm devices, it's located at `/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata` (symlink). For MediaTek (`MTK`) and other SoCs, the path is slightly different. You can find all block devices or `by-name` directory using `find` command:

```
~# find /dev -type b
~# find /dev -type d -name 'by-name'
```

Or by hit and trial:

```
~# ls -d /dev/*/by-name
~# ls -d /dev/*/*/by-name
~# ls -d /dev/*/*/*/by-name
```

**Note:**

- If your `/data` partition has [Full Disk Encryption (FDE)](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk) you need to decrypt it before exposing to UMS because decrypting Android's FDE on PC is near to impossible in most cases due to hardware-backed encryption. See some relevant explanation in my answer to [Cross-platform compatible encryption of SD-card for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215491). [`dm-crypt`](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/DMCrypt) decrypts the block device to [`/dev/block/dm-[N]`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r45/MetadataCrypt.cpp#161). Use this instead of `userdata`.
- To prevent any data loss, it's recommended to create a dump when the partition is not mounted i.e. in recovery mode.

### CREATING PARTITION DUMP:

**DISK DUMP (`dd`)**
Once the block device is known, you can use the `dd` command from:

- ADB shell (OS or custom recovery)
- A terminal emulator app like Termux

Since the `userdata` partition is the largest partition (all other partitions are hardly using 5GB out of total storage), you can't dump it to your internal memory. An external SD card with larger capacity is needed.

To create the dump:

```
~# dd if=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata of=/path/to/ext_sdcard/data.img
```

**ADB**
If you don't want to use an external SD card, you can also dump the partition directly to PC. First you need a working `adb` setup, running as root. Then it can be used in multiple ways:

```
~$ adb exec-out dd if=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata > data.img
```

<sup>* Make sure your `adb` binary (on Windows or Linux) supports [exec-out](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r45/adb/commandline.cpp#1553).</sup>

But you may end up with corrupted data when writing a whole large-sized partition to `STDOUT` of terminal because there are issues with line break types (`CR` and `LF`). Also `STDOUT` or `STDERR` from the programs involved could possibly be added to the file if not directed to `/dev/null`. Even a single wrong byte may render filesystems un-mountable. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578416/read-binary-stdout-data-from-adb-shell) for reference.

To avoid unwanted characters, use `stty raw` and/or `dos2unix`:

```
~$ adb shell 'stty raw && dd if=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata' > data.img
```

But the most straightforward way is:

```
~$ adb pull /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata data.img
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26967862/9165920) for more details.

**STREAM OVER TCP**
To avoid the terminal-related complications described above or if for some reason [`adbd` cannot be run as root](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213429/218526), it's also possible to create a minimal TCP server for data transfer. Forward the port from phone to PC and run a `netcat` TCP server in listening mode:

```
~$ adb reverse tcp:1024 tcp:1024
~$ nc -v -l -p 1024 </dev/null | pv -ab >data.img
```

On phone:

```
~# cat /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata | busybox nc 127.0.0.1 1024
```

**USB TETHERING (RNDIS)**
To avoid using ADB at all, USB tethering can be used to provide network connectivity:

```
~# cd /sys/class/android_usb/android0
~# echo -n 0 >enable
~# echo -n rndis,adb >functions
~# echo -n 1 >enable
```

<sup>* You may also change other files like `{iSerial,iProduct,iManufacturer}` and `f_rndis/{ethaddr,manufacturer,wceis,rndis_transports,max_pkt_per_xfer}` in the above directory if required.</sup>
<sup>* On new devices you might need to use `/config` interfaces instead of `/sys`. Some relevant hints [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205559/218526).</sup>

Add IP address:

```
~# busybox ip rule add lookup main
~# busybox ip address add 192.168.1.1/30 dev rndis0
~# busybox ip link set rndis0 up
```

On PC add IP manually (there's no DHCP server):

```
~$ sudo ip address add 192.168.1.2/30 dev usb0
~$ nc -v -l -p 1024 </dev/null | pv -ab >data.img
```

On phone:

```
~# busybox nc 192.168.1.2 1024 </dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata
```

In the same way it's also possible to use `rclone rcat` to transfer the dump over WebDAV or FTP or SFTP. See [How to stream an encrypted backup of the entire device to remote host?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219261/218526)

**USB MASS STORAGE (UMS)**
This method is useful if you don't want to create a dump of the partition, but instead access partition directly on PC. See my answer to [Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205251) for methods on how to enable UMS thorough `/sys` or `/config` interfaces.

Once done, `userdata` will appear as a partition on Linux PC just as we connect a USB drive. If `/dev/sda` is the hard disk drive, usually `/dev/sdb` will be the `userdata` partition. You can find that by using `blkid` command:

```
~# blkid | grep userdata
/dev/sdb: PARTLABEL="userdata" PARTUUID="..."
```

You can run recovery programs directly on the block device or mount the filesystem (if needed) or may also create a dump.

### HOW TO RECOVER DATA?

There are basically two ways to recover deleted data as mentioned in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214496/218526): carving method and through the filesystem.

Recovery tools mostly don't need mounting filesystems but if it's required, it needs to be done on Linux PC because Windows doesn't support `ext4` or `f2fs` natively, hence the tools aren't easily available AFAIK.

<sup>*If anyone has been able to successfully make block/journal level access to Linux/Android filesystem for data recovery on Windows through [Ext3Fsd](https://github.com/matt-wu/Ext3Fsd) or any other driver, let me know so that I can update the answer.*</sup>

On Linux you can use tools like [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/) to recover data using filesystem journal:

```
~# extundelete --restore-all data.img
```

Or to recover data directly with UMS:

```
~# extundelete --restore-all /dev/sdb
```

Since you have done a factory reset which erases the filesystem, consider carving method using tools like [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) or `scalpel`:

```
~# testdisk data.img
```

In the same way you can use any other data recovery tools. See the ArchWiki on [File Recovery](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_recovery#List_of_utilities) for more details.

---

**RELATED:**

- [How to get data off a completely dead Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215445/218526)
- [How to take full image backup of eMMC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203913/218526)
- [Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205559/218526)
- [Is there any way to recover data from 2nd SD partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/190852/218526)
- [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Comment: you just forgot to tell mount the fstype. use mount with `-t ext4 -o loop,ro,noexec,noload` and instead of `adb exec-out` you could just use `adb pull /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata` or `adb pull /dev/block/dm-0` https://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2011/06/14/digital-forensics-mounting-dirty-ext4-filesystems

Comment: @alecxs mentioning fstype isn't necessary; mount binary can guess a number of commonly used filesystems. No `-t` is actually `-t auto`. `adb pull` is worth-mentioning. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: mount can not detect fstype for loop mounts, especially for dirty mounts (see link)

Comment: @alecxs you must be right, though the link you mentioned is a bit outdated. But I never came across such situation that `mount` couldn't guess filesystem type including `ext4`, `f2fs`, `ntfs` and `exfat`, either from loop file or block device. [busybox mount](https://github.com/yashdsaraf/busybox/blob/1_29_stable/util-linux/volume_id/ext.c#L58) as well as [toybox mount](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/toybox/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/toys/other/blkid.c#104) can detect filesystem type.

Comment: Both also should handle losetup of loopback files automatically (see [this](https://github.com/yashdsaraf/busybox/blob/1_29_stable/util-linux/mount.c#L2031) and [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/toybox/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/toys/lsb/mount.c#33)). Same is true for full `mount` binary from `util-linux`. So if filesystem isn't corrupted and mount binary isn't buggy, I don't think `-t` is necessary.

Comment: tested without -t and works! However, in my forensic scripts i often got "invalid argument" when just -t was missing, and i made some tests and figured out this happens for loop mounts. on the other hand i did know loop is not necessary for busybox, but necessary for mount binary. Things may have changed meanwhile, or it's a special thing of my old debian

Comment: @alecxs you are right. Linux `mount` binary has issues mounting loop file b/c of difference in `/dev/loop*` and `/dev/block/loop*`. `busybox mount` does `mknod` before `LOOP_SET_STATUS` if loop device doesn't exist. Linux `mount` always expects (64) loop devices to exist.

Comment: is extundelete compatible with f2fs?

Comment: @alecxs no. EXT-undelete reads deleted or corrupted data information from the journal of Linux's EXT[N] filesystems. F2FS is not a journaling but log-structured filesystem i.e. roughly saying the whole filesystem is a journal. So the tools developed for one filesystem won't recognize the other at all except the common ioctl's etc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this question I did use the method described above:

```
~$ adb exec-out dd if=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata > data.img
```

But there is an issue, the image will be encrypted if the data is not decrypted first. File and folder names will be gibberish.

The only way I got decrypted data was via TWRP, because it asks for decryption password on start.

And then I was able to copy the data via mtp.

I know this may not seem on topic on how to recover files, but this question is getting a lot of traffic and the proposed solution has a drawback and I'm not allowed to comment right now.

Edit: The original answer does how a way to access the decrypted information that I had not seen.

Comment: From my answer: *“If your `/data` partition has Full Disk Encryption (FDE) you need to decrypt it...”*. The same is applicable to File Based Encryption (FBE). // Also MTP is of no use when it comes to data recovery. Raw access is required to the filesystem or the underlying media.

Comment: You're right, I've updated my answer to reflect that part of your answer.

Comment: **copying** files in TWRP is unrelated to **data recovery** - *"dm-crypt decrypts the block device to /dev/block/dm-0. Use this instead of userdata"* ... for recovery attempts with *extundelete* (from @IrfanLatif answer)

Comment: Actually data recovery with FBE is far more complex than with FDE. With FDE, after decryption, you've the whole filesystem structure intact until it's not `TRIM`ed or `BLKDISCARD`ed. But with FBE the encryption key is also deleted with the deleted file. So along with the actual data, you also have to recover the key or recalculate it, which may or may not work. But to make it work, you surely need a dump of the whole `userdata` partition. After decrypting FBE in TWRP, you have access to only the intact files, not the deleted files and their deleted keys. So I'd say this answer is invalid.

Answer (score -2):

Where exactly in DATA ?
Is it in the emulated SD Card ?
If it's in the emulated SD Card, you could remove your external SD Card and mount the device under USB Mass Storage mode... You can the use free recovery software like Recuva [ccleaner.com/recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva)

However if your file is not in the emulated SD Card, you'd need to backup the Data partition as you mentioned.

To do that, you can either use the device itself to run a DD or CAT command to write the data to a .img file on your SD Card..

**On Device**
Using Terminal Emulator

- locate your -by-name partition directory

  getprop ro.frp.pst

( This will get the /dev/block/platform/DEVICE/by-name directory for frp - change the name to data )
You can just use /data otherwise.

```
dd if=/data of=/sdcard/data.img
```

If = Input file  - Of = Output file

You could also use ADB

**Via Computer**

- Install ADB ( not the entire SDK but just ADB )

Using command prompts or power shell

```
adb shell dd if=/data of=/sdcard/data.img
```

You may need to locate your correct directory.

Then you can Mount the .img on a PC and do the recovery.. I'm not sure how to mount the .img file if the partition is ext4 so that's as far as this answer goes.

You can alternatively use an App called Disk Digger ..
It has the capability to scan the data partition live, ..
Root Access is needed

Comment: `if=/data` won't work, it's just a mountpoint, not the block device. `dd` dumps files, not directories. Secondly, USB Mass Storage can also be used to mount or dump complete `data` partition from custom recovery directly to PC.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize you are using a Custom Recovery... That's extremely simple, just back it up ! .... I know `if=/data` won't work, that's why I said find the `by-name` directory.

Comment: I have a perception that nandroid backups (usually created by `tar`ring) contain only files/directories, not the inode level details of block devices that's required to undelete something.

Comment: No don't use TAR, use DD or Cat to create the image.

Comment: you misunderstand the naming, dd does not work on directories only on files, `by-name` is a symlink to a file not a directory. on linux everything is a file. if= stands for input file

Comment: Ah yes... 'cat' is correct and ( by-name ) gives you a file representation of the .img ... A file.