# File recovery on bootloader unlocked Pixel without flashing

Tags: data-recovery, file-system, 9.0-pie, delete, google-pixel

I have a first generation Google Pixel the bootloader of which is unlocked and is running stock Pie. I need to recover deleted files on it because a move operation got effed up by ES File Explorer with confusing dialogs. Performing file recovery requires root, but I don't want to *install* a custom ROM. Is there instead a way I can run one in RAM that is delivered to the device over USB?

Comment: Root isn't tied to custom ROMs. Just flash Magisk on top of your current ROM.

Comment: @AndyYan Thanks, but I know that. I said I am NOT looking to install a custom ROM. I want to run it over USB.

Comment: I still don't see why you won't. Installing Magisk on top of your current ROM is not installing a custom ROM, can be easily uninstalled, does not affect OTA (if installed correctly), and ultimately your goal is recovering files (admittedly installing has a small theoretical chance of overwriting deleted content, but so does powering up your phone and using it). // On the other hand, the possibility to run arbitrary low-level code over USB sounds too dangerous to be allowed by manufacturers.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is too late but may be helpful for future visitors.

First of all, there are a number of factors which make data recovery impossible, particularly if you keep on using the device. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214496/218526) for more details.

Secondly since you have an unlcked bootloader (but don't want to go with custom ROM), you can flash a custom recovery like TWRP (or boot directly from `fastboot`) and from there dump your `/data` partition to a PC using simply `dd` command or USB Mass Storage (UMS). Then you can apply any data recovery techniques on the partition image e.g. recovering from `journal` or by `carving` through sectors.

For detailed steps: [How to recover a deleted file from /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/218526)