# Recovery approach for lost partition and encrypted F2FS

Tags: recovery-mode, data-recovery, 7.0-nougat, disk-encryption, android-auto

## The Problem and Mystery

My ZTE Axon 7 [Android 7] inexplicably *wiped* its emulated storage area `/storage/emulated/0` while retaining all installed applications, albeit with settings wiped clean. There was also a 256GB sd-card mounted as a add-on, system space. I *think* it was configured as F2FS and encrypted. **I've stopped using it and bought a new phone**. I want to image the phone's internal memory and the sd-card, and recover what I can that wasn't backed up. I don't know the best approach, but know there are *some* hurdles, which I'm unsure how to approach.

1. **What is the best way to image phone memory? Recovery mode and ADB?**

   - The F2FS and internal memory may have been re-partitioned and/or reformatted
   - Getting the image would allow me to scan for text, strings, and file signatures
2. **Where is the encryption key normally kept? Is it backed up anywhere?**

   - The original file systems are likely encrypted, and would need a key
   - I know the phone would store this somewhere, but unsure how to retrieve it.
   - Key may have been overwritten or reset, since I didn't immediately realize something happenend, plus don't fully comprehend what did.
3. **Is there any way to view the contents of a GDrive backup? Any chance it contains key?**

   - There is some backup data on Google Drive, but haven't viewed yet
   - This backup may also have been overwritten, since I see no versioning info
   - Backup data is not very large. Maybe a few megabytes.
4. **How did this happen? Does my story below add up?**

   - I'm hoping there's an alternative cause and fix to this

---

### How it happened

Not sure since I was using *Android Auto* for navigation and music, and the phone was normal. At some point the phone became "weird" with the wrong launcher, which I ascribed to accidentally pressing a wrong button and activating another launcher (I had several installed), and I switched to my wife's phone. Later I realized every app was "weird" and then checked the FS and realized everything, photos, docs, were missing even at the file system level.

*Maybe* I pushed a system upgrade prompt, or *confirmed* some other crazy phone action. I was driving and don't know.

Comment: i am afraid you can do nothing to recover phone because you did not unlock the bootloader. it may caused by f2fs itself (it is buggy) https://forum.xda-developers.com/axon-7/development/recovery-official-twrp-zte-axon-7-t3515715

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/rooting-roms/how-to-backup-qualcomm-phone-root-t3570178

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can unlock the bootloader now, but not sure if it will help

Comment: don't do it now, it is too late. find a exploit for booting twrp without unlocking bootloader. maybe there is some way with Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader 9008 Driver and QPST

Comment: @alexcxs, since my Axon is now an _extra_ phone, after giving up on this data, should I root it anyhow? Root and sell, or just sell? Thanks

Comment: Yes, but I thought you just said "you can do nothing to recover phone because you did not unlock the bootloader. it may caused by f2fs itself". Is there a chance to image the data and try to recover something? - Sorry, just saw your updated comment. Will try the Qualcomm driver

Comment: try the second link to get a dump of your phone with HDDRawCopy. then we will see if the key is recoverable from `/data/misc/vold` this would help to decrypt sdcard. there is a exploit to get the Keymasters Key blob (which may help to recover data from phone dump) but this requires highly expert skills https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/07/01/turns_out_breaking_android_fulldisk_encryption_is_easy_with_the_right_code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover a deleted file from /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208106/how-to-recover-a-deleted-file-from-data-partition)