# How to recover deleted notes from Android device - Huawei P8 Lite?

Tags: data-recovery, linux, bootloader, huawei

I'm very stuck in solving this problem (from more that one year!).

I started accidentally the hard reset of my **Huawei P8 lite**. Luckily I've saved all my photos and document on my SD. The problem is that I had important informations on my memos. I didn't use that phone more to not overwrite data. I explore the features of many software recovey in the market, but nobody has the memos recovery functionality.

I would like to know if it could be possible to recover my **memos** (only that!) in a safe way, without using external softwares, using Windows or Linux environment (and, if is possible, what is in your opinion the best method to unlock the **bootloader** before, because I was not even able to do that).

[I am a new one in the community, so tell me kindly if I'm not respecting some rule]

Thank you very much

Comment: Please explain *“run the **bootloader** before”*.

Comment: Usually all recent Android devices come with enabled device encryption by default. Performing a factory reset deletes the used encryption key and hence data recovery is usually impossible.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Sorry, I'd mean to unlock the bootloader

Comment: @Robert But why can I recover photos from the internal memory of the device? (I tried with Wondershare doc. phone" and with "Android data recovery")

Comment: I was talking about recent devices. Did not notice that we are talking about an ancient device here, released 2015 Android 5 or 6 installed). Your phone is very old and I assume has multiple vulnerabilities. Those data recovery tools use one of the vulnerabilities to gain root access (any other app could do the same) and to search for recoverable files.

Comment: first you need to know the package name of the memo app. second you need to recover the /data/data/<pkgname>/databases/*.db and *.wal files (binwalk may find it). third you need payed software (no free alternatives available). fourth a expert who can restore entries from broken database https://www.forensicfocus.com/Forums/viewtopic/t=13930/ these are 4x nogos sorry

Comment: what you can do is get a hexeditor like HxD and search for known text in partition dump https://android.stackexchange.com/q/208106

Comment: @alecxs thank you very much! I will try... But do I have to work on the device or can I first copy the databases on storage and then work on it? 
How could I know the package name of the memo app?

Comment: **partition dump** mean offline mirror of userdata partition. this device comes with Lollipop, this mean userdata is encrypted. it has Kirin 620 chipset there are no methods for unlocking bootloader. you must root device with Kingroot and dump decrypted userdata

Comment: Thanks. You are very kind! How can I vote your answer?

Comment: @alecxs how can I know the package name of the memo app?

Comment: enable usb-debugging, open memo app and run `adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep Focus`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will share with you the output

Comment: Kingroot was not able to root my phone...