# Weird ftp issue during data recovery of Android phone! Can you solve it?

Tags: windows, data-recovery

I am trying to recover lost data on a Note 3. It is rooted, so I did what I saw here:

http://datas-recovery.com/static/recover-samsung-lost-data.html

I did successfully connect to my phone and set up clonezilla, but I faced a weird problem with this line:

```
ftpput -v -u qwer -p pass -P 40 192.168.42.79 mmcblk0p27.raw /cache/myfifo
```

I did use my computer ip, 127.0.0.1 and localhost, but all failed.

this is the message with localhost and 127.0.0.1 :

> ftpput: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused

and this is the message with my ip address:

> ftpput: can't connect to remote host (192.168.1.50): Network is
> unreachable

OK, for troubleshooting I had tried to get to my ftp server from Firefox in my computer and from another computer. Both connected to my ftp server successfully!

Note: my computer is Windows 10.

Comment: No localhost/127.0.0.1 is not the IP of your phone, that is the loopback network card which is only accessible on the device itself. Therefore if you try to connect to 127.0.0.1 on your Smartphone you try to connect not to your PC but to your smartphone (where of course no FTP server is running). Execute in cmd shell `ipconfig /all`to see all interfaces and their IP addresses. And make sure PC and smartphone are connected to the same network.

Comment: I know that, and as I mention, I did add the ip of my computer but I did get the message I mentioned above. (ftpput: can't connect to remote host (192.168.1.50): Network is unreachable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover a deleted file from /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208106/how-to-recover-a-deleted-file-from-data-partition)

Comment: @alecxs It is good, but I couldn't find data user path, could you help me with that ? please

Comment: `mount | grep ' /data '`

Comment: Thanks @alecxs.
I got this (/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata /data ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,journal_checksum,journal_async_commit,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0).  
So after (adb shell) then (su) I had issued this (adb shell 'stty raw && dd if=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata' > data.img) but got this error (tmp-mksh: can't create data.img: Read-only file system).
Also tried to issue it without (adb shell)&(su) then get a file with this inside (/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata: cannot open for read: Permission denied).

Comment: *adb shell su -c "cat /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata | gzip 2> /dev/null" > userdata.img.gz*