# How to recover deleted photos from a specific directory(folder) in non-rooted device?

Tags: data-recovery

Some bad cleaner app deletes all my photos stored in a directory(folder) which is created manually by myself (for example, `/sdcard/myphoto/`).

I tried some photo recovery apps. But none of them recovered those photos and none of them provides a feature to recover photos from a specific directory. All recovery apps just scan the entire memory and restore all deleted photos once. (Actually most recovered photos are not deleted at all. I have no ideas why they are recovered... Anyway)

Are there any ways to recover deleted photos from a specific directory in non-rooted device? I am explicitly sure which directory those photos are, and I just want those photos only.

Thank you very much.

PS: I know there are questions about photo recovery. But mine is different. The main focus of this question is **"from a specific directory"**.

Comment: Data recovery tools mostly use the "file carving" method which scans for JPEG headers in the partition. Of course by this method you get all images, deleted or not. A good tool may check if a recovered images is already known in the file-system (hence is not deleted) but otherwise this could mean that images that were saved twice on your partition - one still exists, the other deleted - the deleted image would be always ignored.

Comment: @Robert thanks a lot for letting me know the recovery concept in the background.

Comment: @alecxs Thanks for your reply. I don't really know how recovery works. So not sure why the question is how to get partition image. I just want the recovery tool to scan a specific directory for instance `/sdcard/myphoto/` instead of finding all the deleted images in all directories in the partition. Mine is not a mediatek device, it's a Qualcomm Snapdragon 835 device.

Comment: ***“from a specific directory”*** is secondary thing. Without root you don't have access to underlying filesystem (block device), so data recovery isn't possible at all.

Comment: @IrfanLatif thanks for letting me know this. There are many photo recovery apps which do not require root in play store. So are they just lying? Maybe they just scan all caches and dot files and list photos in cach directories instead of a real recover.

Comment: @sgon00 sorry I never tried any of such apps, so can't comment. What I know is that data recovery from filesystem isn't possible without access to block devices, which is restricted in Android. For relevant details see my answer to https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/218526