# File system of Android 10 running devices

Tags: file-system, android-10

I have a samsung A30 cellphone that runs Android 10 and I basically need to recover my deleted files. In order to do that, I need to know the filesystem because forensic tools require such information. I made a small research, but I couldn't find any information on Android 10 OS's file system. So what I am asking is what file system does Android 10 have and do file systems depend on Android versions? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think this would help you https://android.stackexchange.com/q/208106/131553

Comment: if your device is rooted it's ext4 otherwise it's encrypted (and recovery pointless)

Comment: Thank you both @beeshyams and alecxs. I will try to root my device now and lets see how it goes.

Comment: let me clarify: you can not recover files because your device is encrypted. once the encryption keys are wiped, data is unrecoverable. this is true for FDE full-disk-encryption on factory reset, and for FBE file-based-encryption on deleted files. be aware rooting involves factory reset (see [step 4](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-unofficial-twrp-for-galaxy-a30.3968085)). no hope, sorry

Comment: @alecxs so you say it is impossible to recover an unrooted android mobile phone, right? Recovering a wiped (factory-reset) cell phone is possible only on rooted devices.

Comment: it doesn't matter if device is locked/unlocked rooted/unrooted. if it is encrypted it is not possible to recover files. it depends on the encryption key - if the key is wiped it is impossible to decrypt. furthermore even unencrypted device still faces problem with TRIM and discard (the link explains this)

Comment: furthermore samsung encryption is little bit different and TWRP doesn't support samsung encryption. the only way would be to flash magisk_patched.tar on locked bootloader (AVBv1 only) but it's exynos chipset with no EDL mode and no way to flash except modded odin. but you must find the setting not to factory reset on flashing (which is most likely not available, at least i don't know). but samsung has additional protections against rooting and you will most likely end up bricked and lose all data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this [TWRP](https://github.com/crazo7924/twrp_device_samsung_a30/releases) the Samsung Galaxy A30 SM-A305F is shipped with Android 9.0 (Pie) `FDE` full-disk-encryption

`BoardConfig.mk`

```
# Filesystem
TARGET_USERIMAGES_USE_EXT4 := true
TARGET_USERIMAGES_USE_F2FS := true
```

The file system type depends on ROM and can be `F2FS` or `EXT4`