# how to recover data from android 10?

Tags: data-recovery

**My Samsung A80 had an issue and could start up**
i had to flash it
tried to recover its data but could not
i  HAVE used windows and i used different apps, no thing worked
my friend rooted the phone SO MY PHONE IS ROOTED
the rooting is verified
used more programs and apps
nothing worked
DrFONE
Disk digger
all says its rooted but no data recovered
THIS IS ALL WHAT I DID
what should i do?

Comment: If encryption was disabled, you can use NAND flash chip programmer to recover data.

Comment: or in other words, no data is recoverable because your phone was encrypted

Comment: how can i make sure that my phone was not encrypted ?

Comment: i flashed it and now i just rooted it trying to recover data, so no way to recover any thing cuz its encrypted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover a deleted file from /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208106/how-to-recover-a-deleted-file-from-data-partition)

Answer (score 2):

New versions of Android force disk encryption. Since your device is not so old and it was unrooted before the wipe happened, the encryption was definitely enabled.

I do not want to disappoint you, but the fact is that no data can be recovered anymore from the device. The encryption uses a security key that is stored on-device. A new encryption key is generated when you reset the device to encrypt the storage again. So, in the absence of the old encryption key, you will not be able to decrypt the data even if your recovery software manages to recover some bytes.

I'd recommend to avoid wasting time and other valuable resources to recover the data now. It is permanently gone.