# I'm looking for a data recovery program for my android phone

Tags: internal-storage, data-recovery, windows, samsung-galaxy-j7

I had a Samsung Galaxy J7 it was stolen I managed to get it back but not before it was wiped completely but they weren't able to get passed the frp lock and I had some very valuable data on some of witch is not replaceable my question is since nothing was saved over the old data and I've got access to developer settings is there a program for windows 10 that I can get to recvoer my data preferably a free program
I'd even be willing to try rooting it if I knew it would get my data back

Comment: sorry your data is lost forever, no way to recover encryption key from factory reset

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover a deleted file from /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208106/how-to-recover-a-deleted-file-from-data-partition)