# Samsung "My Files" app: where is trash?

Tags: samsung, data-recovery, restore, delete, my-files

#### Situation

There is a Samsung A10 with Android 9. Some files are deleted by `My Files` app. I tried to find its *trash* tool by [this post](https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S-Phones/where-is-the-trash-in-quot-my-files-quot-app/td-p/1300469):

> Open my files. Tap the 3 vertical dots in the upper right corner. On the menu that opens select settings. On the settings menu scroll down to make sure **trash is turned on**.

For me, there is no option to enable *trash*.

> If you're not seeing anything that says trash then you might try looking for a my files version **update** in the galaxy store.

I updated `My Files` app, but still there is no option to turn *trash* on.

#### Question

Am I missing something? How can I see *trash* in Samsung `My Files` app?

#### Other questions

1. I tried some apps like these to recover deleted files. Some of them did find some old deleted photos, but *not* the ones which are deleted today:

   1. [diskdigger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?hl=en&id=com.defianttech.diskdigger)
   2. [dumpster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.baloota.dumpster&hl=en)
   3. [digdeep](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greatstuffapps.digdeep&hl=en&gl=US)
2. I also tried `Gallery` app: its *trash* is enabled but its restore didn't work. I think because the files are deleted by `My Files` app, *not* `Gallery` app. Not sure.
3. What else I can try to restore deleted photos and videos in `My Files` app?

#### Yet another question

I tried [undelete](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.undelete) app. It mentions that there is no *root* mode:

> Without root, the application can only recover cached images.

How can I root the device without messing it up? Just to be able to use `undelete` app.

Comment: Don’t try to root just to undelete something. Following that path requires a full factory reset. Once you factory reset a lot more data gets deleted and finding your currently deleted data among that would be very difficult (impossible if it gets overwritten by that time). If your Files app doesn't offer trash despite being fully updated, than it means it never had trash option to begin with when your data was deleted. And even if you somehow end up installing an update which introduces trash option, you still wouldn't achieve anything. Because when data was deleted, trash wasn't there.

Comment: ...as trash wasn't there, your data was instantly deleted, instead of being classified as trash. You can learn about data recovery  if in case, you have had root access. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/96277

Comment: @Firelord Right, it makes sense.

Comment: @Firelord Trying to avoid such a data loss in the future, what's the standard approach I should use? Any app? Any tool? Is there any related post that I can study? I appreciate it if you point me in the right direction =)

Comment: Currently, there is no standard approach. You can be prepared by having a rooted phone or at least a custom recovery such as Twrp installed. After that, what you can try depends on some factors. This post has covered this topic well enough. You can try reading it to get a heads-up what you would need to do in future. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/96277