# Android internal storage files recovery method that still work in android 10

Tags: root-access, data-recovery, android-10

I have a realme 5 phone running Android 10 and realmeUI 1.0. I accidently deleted whole folder containing pictures and a few videos. Is there any method that still works in android 10 since the methods I have read on this platform as well as on other websites are from 2015-16.

Deleted from: internal storage

NO ROOT and bootloader is NOT unlocked.
Although I'm ready to root if that could help recover all my data. If data recovery is possible without root that would be better but if not I'm ready to root.

Also since the phone is secured by passcode (the data must have been encrypted(?)) and if I root it directly without doing away with passcode will the data (images and videos) be readable by data recovery software. Or I should do away with passcode (which will decrypt data) and then root so that the decrypted data can be read by data recovery software.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: On recent devices the internal user storage is always encrypted no matter if you have set a password or not. Rooting will not help you because this will erase all user data and also delete the encryption key which makes recovery impossible. But without root to my knowledge recovery is also not possible as you don't get direct access to the flash memory. Therefore I don't see a way to recover your data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover a deleted file from /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208106/how-to-recover-a-deleted-file-from-data-partition)

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.i8dudata.imgrecover.free