# Recover deleted file from /data without root

Tags: rooting, data-recovery, huawei, 9.0-pie

I have a non-rooted P30 lite which I no longer use. To cut a long story short, there are about 100 files (mix of PDF and videos) I need within my /data directory that were deleted about a week ago which I could do with recovering. I'm aware that it is possible that the memory has been trim'd in this timeframe. The phone was only used for two days after they were deleted before I turned off the phone after upgrading.

I have found this answer here: [How to recover a deleted file from /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208106/how-to-recover-a-deleted-file-from-data-partition) but unfortunately it needs the phone to be rooted. I can't root the phone as the bootloader cannot be unlocked. I have full access to the phone and everything on the phone works fine.

What options do I have for trying to recover these files? As I no longer use the phone, I am happy to risk the phone/use potentially destructive methods to recover them.

Comment: you haven't read the linked question correctly. It's not about root is required, it tells you (even with root) *"WHAT MAKES RECOVERY OF DELETED DATA **IMPOSSIBLE**: file/directory is simply deleted from File Explorer app or from commandline + Filesystem on device is Flash Filesystem F2FS + Filesystem is (SECURE) TRIM or ERASE + Deleted file is **encrypted** (so no file carving is possible)"* either files still exist in trash can or they were already lost in the exact moment of delete

Comment: that's annoying. thanks @alecxs