# Backing up a partition to desktop with adb and pv

Tags: adb, backup, partitions

I had once found a fast method to backup device partitions to a computer using `adb` and `pv` (provided by a TWRP temporary boot image). `pv` ran on the Android device and was called using `adb`, specifically, I think, using `adb exec-out`. `cat` might have been involved. `dd` was not used, I'm 85% sure of that, because I need/needed to see the copy progress.

I am unable to find it now. What was it?

Comment: Isn't `pv` a tool uses for monitoring progress, how can you backup a partition using that tool? Also if you intend to pipe the data from Android to the host PC using `adb shell` you will recognize that this will change the transferred data (net lines). Better use `adb exec-out`.

Comment: See "CREATING PARTITION DUMP" heading in this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/218526

Comment: @Robert "Monitoring progress" is vague. I've mostly seen `pv $A $B` to copy one partition to another or to a file while displaying the operation's progress, which I need to see to know that a copy operation hasn't stalled. I probably did use `adb exec-out` instead of `adb shell`.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Your linked answer uses `dd` which is inefficient and does not display the progress.

Comment: @Melab I've just counted. I described 7 methods there to create a partition dump. Seems like you are in a hurry. So what you can do is open the linked answer, press `Ctrl + F` in your browser, and type `" pv "` without quotation marks. The search results will quickly lead you to 2 commands in which I've used `pv`. None of the both uses `dd`. // Btw I hope you are aware of `dd status=progress ...`. If not, please read [here](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html). Also see [pv](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pv.1.html) to correct your understanding of how it works.

Comment: *'adb pull -p /dev/block/dm-0'* will give you progress bar