# How do I restore deleted video? Xiaomi forces me to log in to their cloud when I open the Gallery's trash

Tags: restore, xiaomi, video, 8.1-oreo

An important video from my wife's phone was deleted by accident today. I want to restore it. The phone is Redmi 5 plus, Android 8.1.0, MIUI Global 11.0.2.

When I go to Gallery, instead of opening the local trash folder, it forces me to log in to Xiaomi Cloud. When I try to log in to the cloud, it says that it will send SMS but instead, it was calling twice and then sending SMM once. The call interrupts the internet connection and as a result, that field to enter number disappears, and even though it says number during a call as a voice message, I have no place to input it. And the code from SMS wasn't accepted. Then it said that I was out of maximum attempts to log in.

I don't understand why would I have to log in to use the local trash folder. If I had to sync with the cloud first, and without it, I can't restore it - then I don't care about that Xiaomi Cloud.

Is there still any possible way to restore that video? Preferably a free one.

P.S. Just in case. I've been trying to install Wondershare Dr.Fone. It turned out to be such a peace of ssssoftware... First, it offers a free download, a long installation of the whole package, and no choice for a separate tool. Then it shows something it found (which seems to be already existing videos and I didn't see the one I needed) and then when I click "recover" it wants me to pay money. Yea, right.

Then I tried Recuva from my PC, marked the phone as a target folder, and connected via USB in a photo-sharing mode ("photos sharing P2P" - something like that). Didn't find a single video. The trash in the phone's system gallery redirects to the cloud login form.

Google Photos was set up previously but for some reason, it didn't upload video automatically, which I also don't understand. On my phone, it's the same: photos are uploaded automatically, but videos need explicit confirmation every time even though settings say explicitly "automatically upload photos and videos".

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. We have a canonical for [recovering data](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/208106/44325), though it's quite technical. Meanwhile, how did she delete the video? Is it from a certain app? As for Google Photos, I don't know if the video was actually backed up or not, but Google Photos's "Delete" option deletes on both device *and cloud*, though the user should have been warned through a confirmation dialog.

Comment: Google Photos had settings to not use mobile internet. And she was constantly using mobile internet, not wifi, so it wasn't synced before deletion. I'm not sure which program did that. She wanted to send it to me via one of messenger apps but something went wrong and she said that there was some popup with mentioning "1 file" and question. She didn't read it and just tapped "yes" or "ok". I guess that's the one that deleted it. But I didn't see it and she didn't pay attention to it, so no one knows for sure which program has deleted it.