# Create an exact image of the internal storage

Tags: backup, data-recovery, realme

My relative lost all her photos by clicking on "format data" on her Realme 7 recovery menu (the one popping up at startup when holding together the volume down and power button - found out after that the volume down button was broken and like kept hold down by itself).

I'd like to create an exact image of the internal storage to try to recover the possible because the phone is not rooted and I need to root it to enable the USB mass storage mode.

Is there any way to do this? Is the Realme 7 encrypted like other phones, so it's completely useless?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. There's a canonical FAQ about [How to recover a deleted file from /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/208106/44325) to help check if the data can be recovered or not; and if it is, how to recover them. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `userdata` partition is encrypted and dump completely useless. Anyway, exact image can be created with MTKClient.